# how to install anbox ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, 20.04

How to install anbox This does not load Why is Kernel Ashmen not downloading If you do not have an answer to this tell me how to install android apps

Comment: Please clarify or correct your release details; you've tagged you're using 14.04 (and EOL or ESM release) but also mention Ubuntu 20.04 ?  Which are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The Android emulator is available as a Snap, so you can install it like this:

```
sudo snap install --beta --devmode anbox
```

From there you can start the session and application managers:

```
anbox session-manager
anbox.appmgr
```

That's really all there is to it. If you get a message like "Failed to connect to DBus", then you'll need to install the `dbus-x11` package:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dbus-x11
export $(dbus-launch)
```

When done, restart the session and app managers:

```
anbox session-manager
anbox.appmgr
```